# How to check type of Directory Server using JNDI?

Tags: active-directory, jndi, apacheds, directory-server

Is there any way to find DS type whether it is Active Directory or Apache DS ?

in other words :- 
Lets say I create a context using DS URL and credentials using JNDI. Does context says anything about DS like this DS is Active Directory or anything else ?

Comment: It's hard to see how you would know a valid DN and its credentials without also knowing the DS type.

Comment: scenario : - Yes, DS type/url/credentials are known in advance but restrict to connect application to DS if it is Active Directory, allow to connect if it is Apache DS.